# Spark Snowflake connectivity Through JDBC Driver

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, private-key

I am trying to create spark dataset from snowflake through JDBC driver. In the Below code, getPrivateKey method parse the PEM through Bouncy Castle provider and returns Java.security.PrivateKey object. This code works fine when I am connecting through DriverManager.

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop)
```

But When I am trying to connect through SparkSession. I am getting error like
*sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String*
If I am passing privatekey string, then Getting error like JDBC is expecting PrivateKey object not string.

if I am passing private_key_file and private_key_file_pwd instead of privateKey, then I am getting null pointer exception.

```
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("user", "<user>");
connectionProperties.put("db", "<DB>");
connectionProperties.put("schema", "<schema>");
connectionProperties.put("warehouse", "<warehouse>");
connectionProperties.put("privateKey", getPrivateKey("<p8File>","<passpharse>"));
//connectionProperties.put("private_key_file", "<p8File>");
//connectionProperties.put("private_key_file_pwd", "<passpharse>");
connectionProperties.put("useSSL", "true");

String driverName="com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver";
                
resultDataset =  sparkSession.sqlContext().read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("dbtable", "store")
                .option("driver", driverName)
                .jdbc("jdbc:snowflake://<AccountWithRegion>.snowflakecomputing.com", "store", connectionProperties);
```

Could please help me to pass private key in Spark JDBC driver?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this , i am facing the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I just resolved it now.

You need to use the format as "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake". Something as below and pass the key as string. You also need to change other parameter names to sfURL,sfSchema etc. Convert the key to a pem String and then pass it

```
spark.read().format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake").option("pem_private_key",key)
```